# MySql between 2 date range query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Hello I have one question, I have one column name is logs and have this data:

```
04-9-2018 17:53:48
06-9-2018 12:07:13
16-11-2018 12:04:17
23-11-2018 12:11:59
```

My query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE logs BETWEEN '06-7-2018 00:53:48' AND '07-9-2018 23:53:48'
```

Result is just: **06-9-2018 12:07:13**

For this my query starts from **06 July** and ended **07 September** for this why is not display **04-9-2018 17:53:48**

for more im builded database, this is link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4f2ca/3

Comment: Use str_to_date function to convert your logs (character) to date

Comment: sqlite or mysql?

Answer (score 1):

because your logs data type is not date time

you define in time of table creation `logs` varchar(250) type

Now change it to datetime and check it will work

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c36d/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `logs` datetime  NOT NULL

) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table` (`logs`) VALUES
  ('2018-09-04 17:53:48'),

  ('2018-09-06 12:07:13'),

  ('2018-11-16 12:04:17'),

  ('2018-11-23 12:11:59');

select * from `table` where logs BETWEEN 
'2018-07-06 00:53:48' AND '2018-09-07 23:53:48'

logs
2018-09-04T17:53:48Z
2018-09-06T12:07:13Z
```